# javascript don't find every element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

data is a string with an id and a budget: `"3_1470300029;44_62648640,8207444;46_7168,80036952867"`
Every element changes with this function but the last (46) don't, except in Internet Explorer. In other browsers it don't find the element inputNumber46, while it does excist.

```
function(data) {
  alert(data);
  var dataArray = data.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].split("_");
  }
 for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    var waarde = dataArray[i];
    alert(waarde[0] + " " + waarde[1]);
    $('#totaal' + waarde[0]).html("€ " + waarde[1]);
    $("#inputNumber" + waarde[0]).val(waarde[1]);
 }
```

Comment: What is problem? See https://jsfiddle.net/n5ptd1uv/

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: It hasn't any problem to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `$.each()` for plain array. Use ordinary loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    var waarde = dataArray[i];
    alert(waarde[0] + " " + waarde[1]);
    $('#totaal' + waarde[0]).html("€ " + waarde[1]);
    $("#inputNumber" + waarde[0]).val(waarde[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= dataArray.length; i++) {
    dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].split("_");
}
```

Comment: What is diffrence of your code with question code?!